# .FBX "bruh" - Flying doors

Tags: animation, .fbx, unreal-engine

I was making an asset for my game (powered by UE4) and when I exported it, the doors that open to release the minigun act strangely. They are flying above instead of opening.

If I export mesh only, everything looks fine, but once I export it with it's armature, it goes "bruh". Any idea what happens when exporting?

https://we.tl/t-fkJHkVmz5M

[image]

Comment: Please don't delete and post the same question more than once. See [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: What does it mean to go 'bruh'? Please explain thoroughly what how you've setup your scene and the steps you took to export it, without resorting to any type of slang, so we are able to diagnose the issue